# only trivial automorphism on Frucht graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Why is there only the trivial automorphism on the Frucht graph?

We have a rooted tree in the Frucht graph which allows to totally order the vertices. But how does this imply that there is only the identity on the Frucht graph?

Comment: What do you mean by 'we have a rooted tree in the Frucht graph' ?

Comment: We can find a spanning tree in the Frucht graph, which covers each vertex and actually is a path. That allows to define a total order on the set of vertices.

Comment: The graph has three Hamiltonian cycles, so that gives you 36 paths which cover the vertices. In other words, that total order you can define is quite not unique. Usually, to find automorphisms or to show there are very few of them, you need to find something of which there are few (like the triangles, or the vertex $v$ in my answer), not many.

Answer (score 4):

The graph contains exactly three triangles (induced graphs isomorphic to $K_3$) so these must be permuted by any automorphism. Now look at the distances between these triangles: an automorphism must preserve them; exactly one triangle is one edge away from the other two, so it must be preserved by an isomorphism. This almost gets you there. Now finish :-)

[image]

Alternatively, there are three vertices which are not in triangles, so they must be permuted among themselves by an automorphism. Exactly one of these three vertices, call it $v$, is at distance three from one of the triangles, so it must be fixed by any automorphism; now exacty one of the other special vertices is at distance one from $v$, so it must be fixed, and the other special vertex must then also be fixed. We thus see that the three vertices not on triangles must be fixed. Continue in this way.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my problem is, that while it seems intuitively clear, that distances are preserved by any automorphism, I do not know how to make that precise. Also that those triangles must be permuted seems intuitively clear, but I always hesitate to appeal to intuitive arguments, as long as I lack there rigorous counterparts..

Comment: Well, find proofs of these facts: they are rather easy and will provide you with little useful exercises.

Comment: Do not hesitate to use intuitive arguments: find actual proofs supporting those arguments instead, which is an immensely more productive use of your energy! The idea that rigorous arguments would go in a direction different from the intuitive ones is rather extraordinary :-)